# TestFlightapp.com going to shutdown on 2/26/2015 and there will not be any way to share apps without app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

As many of you noticed that TestFlight going to be shutdown. So anymore it will be avaible only on iTunesConnect and as i watched the video testers can use this apps only for 30 days which sent by testFlight on iTunesConnect. It means there wont be any way to share apps without app store? Why apple doing something like that?
We sometimes develop apps only for some company's users and these apps are not for app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the last WWDC I sat down with an Apple employee and asked about this exact thing. The response was that there are two ways to develop apps for specific companies that are approved by Apple and do not break the Terms and Conditions for iOS development.

1. If you are providing the source code the the company you are building the app for, have that company get an Apple developer account and make you a developer.
2. If you are building the app but do not want to provide the source code, you have the company you are building it for join the Apple Volume Purchasing program (http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/). You then submit the app to the App Store with that company as the VPP customer (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/B2B.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

[Hockey App](http://hockeyapp.net)

They provide useful crash report data, and other neat options as different app states(Alpha, Beta, Enterprise, Store). With it you can select your app as public page it would be available to download.

Answer (score 1):

[Crashlytics beta](http://www.crashlytics.com/blog/launching-beta-by-crashlytics/) can be used in the same way as testflight before